# C stack odd behavior

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack

I am using the Hope functional program on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.2, and doing a highly recursive function to find a large number of prime numbers. However, I get a segmentation fault:  0x000000000040e03f in reach

```
cell=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff8> at runtime.c:250
```

The segmentation fault occurs when accessing address 0x7fffff7feff8.

What the reach routine is doing is unmarking heap items that can be reached by the current expression (using a garbage collection mark-sweep).  The stack is very deep (100000+ calls), but there is not a stack overflow:

```
base_memory = 0x7ffff35a4010
top_string = 0x7ffff35a5260
BaseHeap = 0x7ffff35a5260
heap = 0x7ffff603a450
stack = 0x7ffff72da498
TopStack = 0x7ffff7584d60
```

The area from base_memory to TopStack was allocated with malloc.

Whenever I get a segment violation, the address is always  0x7fffff7feff8, even with very different functions.

If you google  0x7fffff7feff8 there are quite a few entries with segment violations with this address, with no solution to the problem.

I put code into check that the heap address was in the heap range, but it never failed.

I did a gdb

```
find 0x7ffff35a4010,0x7ffff7584d60,0x7fffff7feff8
```

and nothing was found.

Why does the address `0x7fffff7feff8` show up in so many problems? Is there something amiss with the stack mechanism, or do I need to change the code in some way for the platform?

Comment: Where is the code> (BTW i you like finding large prime numbers you need to get out more!)

Comment: I think the code is quite complex. What I am asking is there some sort of pattern or common error, since the error address 0x7fffff7feff8 seems to appear quite a bit on google, and using gdb the segment violation does not make sense.

Comment: Running the program under `valgrind` may suggest where the problem is. If you already did it, just skip this comment :)

Comment: I will try valgrind, probably tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rather looks like a stack overflow on an x86-64 system without adress space layout randomization. If the stack begins at `0x7ffffffff000`, as they do on such systems, `0x7fffff7feff8` is suspiciously close to 8 MB below the beginning of the stack, which is a common default thread stack size on Linux systems.

Dump the contents of `/proc/self/maps` and check if the start of the stack matches this (it is listed at the bottom), and check `ulimit -s` to see the stack size new processes get. If `/proc/self/maps` lists `0x7ffffffff000` as end of the stack address range and`ulimit -s` prints `8192`, what you have is simply a stack overflow. In this event, a quick fix would be to increase the stack size of new processes (subprocesses of the active shell) like so:

```
ulimit -Ss size_in_kilobytes
```

This will work up to a hard limit `root` may or may not impose. In the long run, it would probably be a good idea to rewrite the code in a less excessively recursive manner.

Also, if all this hits home, you should probably enable ASLR (`sysctl kernel.randomize_va_sapce=1`. If that complains, your system is in dire need of an upgrade. Write `kernel.randomize_va_space = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it permanent).

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  Writing kernel.randomize_va_space = 1 to /etc/sysctl.conf made the most difference, but changing ulimit -s also helped.  In functional programming, most everything is done with recursion. You can try to make things tail recursive, so the stack size doesn't get so big.  I am now a happy camper.

Comment: correction:  There was no difference using ASLR, but a large difference with changing ulimit -s

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. ASLR should only change the location of the stack, not its size, and the code would grow it just the same way from a different starting point. With ASLR, you should see a different stack range in `/proc/self/maps`, and the stack overflow should happen at a different address, though.